# Is static_assert supposed to work when invoked via decltype expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, static-assert

I expect the following code to fail with a `static_assert` check on the final line. However in MSVC2015 and gcc 6.2, it compiles sucessfully. It does fail to compile as expected in clang 3.9. Is this a compiler bug or does `static_assert` not work inside `decltype()`?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {};

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr std::tuple<T, U> operator|(Wrapper<T>, Wrapper<U>)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value == false, "can't combine two of the same type");
    return std::tuple<T, U> {};
}

struct A {};
struct B {};
constexpr Wrapper<A> aaa = {};
constexpr Wrapper<B> bbb = {};

constexpr auto shouldPass1 = aaa | bbb;
//constexpr auto shouldFail1 = aaa | aaa; // fails static assert as expected
using shouldFail2 = decltype(aaa | aaa);
// ^ doesn't fail in MSVC2015, or gcc 6.2. does fail in clang 3.9
```

**Update #1: Additional Question**

Brian suggested that the `static_assert` would not fire in the `decltype` context because the value has not been explicitly instantiated. So I added an additional test below to explicitly instantiate the `shouldFail2` type <s>, which I think by Brian's logic should cause the `static_assert` to fail.</s> However, the code below does not fail in MSVC2015 or gcc 6.2. <s>Is this one a bug, or have I overlooked something?</s> Edit: It appears that once `decltype` has extracted the type, we are free to use `shouldFail2` without further reference to the definition of `operator|`.

```
shouldFail2 shouldFail3 = {}; // instantiate shouldFail2.
// ^ doesn't fail in MSVC2015 or gcc 6.2.
```

**Update #2**

If I change the definition of `operator|` to use an `auto` (or `decltype(auto)`) with no trailing return type, then the `decltype` expression correctly fails the `static_assert` in gcc 6.2. However this version fails to compile in MSVC2015 (errors C3779, C2088). Edit: as W.F. points out below, omitting the trailing return type is a C++14 feature.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto operator|(Wrapper<T>, Wrapper<U>)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value == false, "can't combine two of the same type");
    return std::tuple<T, U> {};
}

...

using shouldFail2 = decltype(aaa | aaa);
// ^ now this correctly fails the static_assert in gcc 6.2
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use your `shouldFail2` somewhere?

Comment: @KirillKobelev I've just updated the question to do exactly that. It still doesn't fail in MSVC2015 or gcc 6.2!

Comment: In your instantiation of `ShouldFail2`, it has type `std::tuple<Wrapper<A>, Wrapper<B> >`. In other words, the type is already known. You are not causing a later instantiation of `operator|`. So, it musn't fail. And as `Brian` says, a definition of the instantiation isn't requiered to know its return type, since it can be deduced from the input parameters (`U` and `T`, when calling it).  However, in the `auto` case, the return type is deduced from the `return` expression, which requires an instantiation, and thus, the `static_assert` check.

Comment: Isn't auto return type without `-> type` c++14 feature?

Comment: @W.F. Correct, I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe GCC and MSVC are correct, and Clang is incorrect. The `static_assert` should not fire, because according to the Standard at [temp.inst]/3:

> Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that
>   requires a function definition to exist.

Inside an unevaluated context such as `decltype`, it is valid to have a call to a function that is left undefined, so this is not such a context in which the function definition is required to exist. Therefore the `static_assert` declaration in the body of the specialization is not instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a follow on question that seems to suggest that there might still be a bug. What do you think?

Comment: @RossBencina: That still doesn't require a definition of your `operator |`, so it still won't instantiate the template specialization.

Comment: @user2357112 if I change `operator |` to use an `auto` return type would it require it to be instantiated?

Comment: @user2357112 see Update #2 in question.

Comment: @RossBencina If you make the return type `auto` then the definition must exist so that the return type can be deduced. So in that case the `static_assert` would definitely fire.

Comment: [temp.inst]p3 only means that the standard does not require the template to be instantiated (meaning GCC and MSVC are correct), it does not rule out some other part of the standard allowing the template to be instantiated (meaning clang could be correct as well). You need [temp.inst]p11 to say clang is incorrect.